# Behaviour subject with subscription using angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular 4 with observable.

I need to shared data one component to another because i am using behaviour subject with observable.

Here is my code

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

public _searchResultOne = new Subject<any>();
searchResultOne$ = this._searchResultOne.asObservable();


constructor(private http: Http) {}

newsearch() {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
        this.http.get(API),
        this.http.get(API)
    )
        .subscribe(latestValues => {
            const [data_changes, data_all] = latestValues;
            this._searchResultOne.next(latestValues);
        })
}

getNewSearchResults(): Observable < any > {
    return this.searchResultOne$;
}
```

Actually i displayed data with load more.Get result using this function getNewSearchResults().

Here is my component.

```
import { SearchService } from '../../shared/services/search.service';
import { ISubscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

results;

constructor(
    public searchService: SearchService) {

}
ngOnInit() {
    this.searchOne();
}
searchOne() {
    this.subscription = this.searchService
        .getNewSearchResults()
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log("result", res);
            var freelisting = res[1].response.docs;
            this.results = this.results.concat(this.freelisitingArray);
        }
}
```

I just consoled the response. its called multiple times.why ?

result is subscribed multiple times so i am getting duplicate results.How can i avoid multiple subscription.

Also i tried to ngOnDestroy with `this.subscription.unsubscribe()`.But still i got more duplicate results.

How can i fix this issues.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're adding `private http: HttpClient` to your constructor

Comment: I also added but why i am getting more subscribtion.Do you knw?

Comment: try HttpClient not Http

Comment: tried.Nothing changes.: (

Comment: You are chaining it wrong way it must not be as observable
searchResultOne$ = this._searchResultOne.asObservable(); 

That may be the cause for issue instead keep that simple use _searchResultOne and make that behaviour subject you are not using a behaviour subject here
Take a subscribe on _searchResultOne

Comment: @niteshbisht.i tried.But still i got same pblm.

Comment: So the problem is fork join please use combineLatestor zip instead.
Fork join will emit the last value returned by each observable read doc here
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to have a singleton service to share it between two (or more) components. If this is the case, take a look at your module code in the `provider: [SearchService]` part,  you must **remove this provider from the components and add just one into the** `app.module.ts.` This way you will have just one instance of the service and preserve the same value in both components.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I did not add searchService in component like provider: [SearchService] .I just added the constructor.